# how to show IP camera stream in my activity

Tags: android, video-streaming, h.264, ip-camera

I want to show video stream from an ip camera in H264 format in my activity. I haven't any experience for video streams in android. How can I achieve this.

Comment: How is the video stream being served? HTTP? RTSP? Something else? http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 3):

To play videos in Android, you can [use `VideoView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html), or the combination of `MediaPlayer` and a surface (`SurfaceView` or `TextureView`). For `VideoView`, use your `http://` or `rtsp:` `Uri` with `setVideoURI()` to have it load the video from the streaming source.

Comment: can u point to  easy to understand tutorial or example please?